# Displaying decimal degrees

Tags: javascript, .net, gis, proj4js

I have a Web Application that displays a Map Service that is in NAD 1927 UTM Zone 15N.  I have JavaScript code that displays the XY in status bar based on where mouse cursor is on that map.  I want to display Latitude/Longitude values instead.  Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a javascript port of the `proj.4` projection system called [proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/).  `proj.4` allows converting from grids to lat/long and vice-versa.

Comment: This sounds promising mtrw.  I don't suppose you have any quick code to show me how to implement this?  I see there is some documentation that I will start reading up on.

Comment: @Josh - I'm afraid not.  I've used `proj.4` in desktop stuff, but I've never done any web development.

Comment: mtrw- How did you get this installed?  My OS is Windows XP.  All the files that came from the zip file are readable in wordpad but I'm confused

Comment: @Josh - I've only ever installed `proj.4`, which is the original C-language version.  If you want to try that, it's available at http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/ (look under the "Binaries" section for prebuilt files).  You can use `invproj` from the command line for the calculation you're looking for.  But getting it into a browser is outside my abilities, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Josh - Does a c# solution work for you?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867950/is-there-a-free-net-library-to-convert-osgb36-to-wgs84/2129570#2129570

Comment: Hi mtrw-  I really need it in javascript if at all possible.  I'll take a look at what you posted to see if this can help.  Thanks,

Comment: Proj4JS isn't a true port. There are examples here: http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/   I'll be adding to the Proj4JS tag wiki later today.